# Using <option> to get ID and post it in another query

Tags: php, mysql, forms, input, pdo

I have a form to insert some data into a table. I'm trying to do this with PDO.
I have a table in my DB where are categories and subcategories. The table has this columns:

**************
id (auto increment)
parent_id (0 for category another number for subcategory)
nume_categorie (varchar with name of category/subcategory)
desc_categorie (varchar with description of category).
In my form I have a select input to get a category from DB.

how can I get the id from a listed category (listed dynamic)?

```
 <select id="categorie" name="categorie">
 <?php
 $stmt = $db->prepare('Select nume_categorie FROM categories WHERE parent_id=0 order by id');
 $stmt->execute();
 while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
 echo '<option>'.$row['nume_categorie'].'</option>';
   }
 ?>
 </select>
```

My query for posting is $categorie .
This variable is:

```
  $categorie = htmlentities(trim($_POST['categorie']));
```

And if it is possible having another select form with subcategories listed from the category selected above.
Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

You should select the id in your query and display it using the value in the $row array:

```
<select id="categorie" name="categorie">
<?php
    $stmt = $db->prepare('Select id,nume_categorie FROM categories WHERE parent_id=0 order by id');
    $stmt->execute();
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo "<option value='".$row['id']."'>".$row['nume_categorie']."</option>";
    }
?>
</select>
```

Comment: ok, but how to insert the selected id?                        $categorie = htmlentities(trim($_POST['categorie']));                        How to insert only the selected id? This is my question

Comment: I've tried this and it insering "nume_categorie" not the id.